# NODEJS - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongoose, lodash

I'm working on a huge project , many functions calling each others

I'm facing this error : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

the full error :

> /Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/lodash.get/index.js:561
>   return reIsPlainProp.test(value) || !reIsDeepProp.test(value) ||
>
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at RegExp.test ()
>       at isKey (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/lodash.get/index.js:561:24)
>       at baseGet (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/lodash.get/index.js:458:10)
>       at get (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/lodash.get/index.js:927:45)
>       at isBsonType (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:150:10)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:210:7)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)
>       at cloneObject (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:270:11)
>       at clone (/Users/mohsen/Desktop/GP/Source/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:196:16)

this error fired exactly when trying to save a new document to my mongo DB

calling the below function

```
saveOrder({data});
```

the function implementation

```
function saveOrder(data)
{
var order = new Order(data);
order.save();
}
```

any suggestions - why I'm facing this issue ??

--- UPDATE ---

commenting order.save(); solve the issue

now the issue with this line

```
order.save();
```

Comment: What your `Order` schema? Did you define some methods there? Like `pre-save`

Comment: @molamk there may be issue with this attribute
in schema {X : Array}
--
when calling it {X: [ { id: 'ID1',
function1: [Function],
function2: [Function],
id: [Circular] },
{ id: 'ID2',
function1: [Function],
function2: [Function],
id2: [Circular] } ]}

Comment: Can you update the question to include the Schema? Thanks

Comment: {data} will create an object like {'data': data} and your schema must be defined in this way. i.e. {data: <complete object>}. 
I think this is the place where you are going wrong so you must call the method like saveOrder(data) however, share your schema and data object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , this answer if someone faced the same issue

the issue was between these 2 types which mongoose schema support

- Mixed
- Array

I used Array in my schema

{ X : Array }

but I inserted it with a array of complex objects
in this case I should use Mixed not Array

to learn more : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html